# Table columns are changing during jQuery.slide()

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, jquery-slider

I have a table where half the data is hidden, and can be expanded by pressing a button.  I am following the pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215219/how-do-i-hide-the-middle-of-a-table-using-jquery).  Here is my html:

```
<button class="toggleBtn">Hide/Show</button>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Session Name : </td>
    <td>Generic name here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jump Date : </td>
    <td>12/25/2011</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="hiddenJumpSessionDetails" style="display:none;">
    
    <tr>
        <td>Created On : </td>
        <td>12/24/2011</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Inspector : </td>
        <td>Gadget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Notes : </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".toggleBtn").click(function()
    {
        $(".hiddenJumpSessionDetails").slideToggle();
    })
})
```

While the hidden part is scrolling up/down, the table acts as though there are 3 columns.  The second column in the first  moves to the right, the second column in the second  moves slightly closer to the left.  The entire second column moves back to the proper place once the slide is complete.

What is making the table behave this way?

Note: this effect doesn't happen when there is no data in the second column in the hidden .  If the '12/24/2011' and 'Gadget' were taken out, everything would seem fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work correctly by setting `display:block` within your `tbody` elements and hiding the element within the script like so:

```
<tbody style="display:block;" >
.
.
.
<tbody class="hiddenJumpSessionDetails" style="display:block;">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".hiddenJumpSessionDetails").hide();
    $(".toggleBtn").click(function () {
      $(".hiddenJumpSessionDetails").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/aa7Kv/

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have any width set on the table or columns, so it will be fluid.

Try setting some width's.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I worked with widths, especially in the <col> tag, but in the end I had to use widths on the <td> tags themselves, in combination with setting the display type of the <tbody> tags.